# How to map a base class to a derived class in Automapper 9.0

Tags: inheritance, automapper, derived-class, base-class

This problem appeared only in Automapper 9, before that everything worked for me.
Here is my data structureЖ

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public BaseEntity Base { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestDto
{
    public BaseDto Base { get; set; }

}

public class BaseDto
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedDto : BaseDto
{
    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
}
```

This code doesn't return me a derived class:

```
var test2 = new TestEntity { Base = new DerivedEntity() };
var testDto2 = mapper.Map<TestDto>(test2);
```

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.